# Are the peculiar One Piece laughs based on anything?

Tags: one-piece

In *One Piece*, there are several strange laughs such as

- Donquixote Doflamingo with his Fuffuffuffuffu
- Dorry with his Gegyagyagyagya

Are laughs like these based on anything? Or are they just randomly chosen for comedic purposes ?

Comment: Odachi in an SBS said that he likes to give different laughs to his characters. Don't know which SBS though.

Comment: The characters' way of laugh may only be a flavour to the anime itself. Shinononononononononono

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In [One Piece](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Laughter_Style), the laughters are very unique and can be based on personalities or appearances of the said characters.

By giving them different laughs, IMO, gives a sense of their aura and keeps the character entertaining.