# Why do characters in One Piece have weird signature suffixes to their lines?

Tags: one-piece

I have seen often that characters in One Piece have their weird (read: at times irritating) signatures. Is there any specific reason for them?

For example, in the picture below, Vito has **`rorero`** as his signature. These suffixes sometimes kill the entire feel of the scene, which is why I was wondering why were they so important to have in the first place.

[image: Example]

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I believe that is them laughing because a very big part of one piece is that each character has a unique way of laughing.

Comment: it's a catch phrase http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3317/what-is-the-significance-of-anime-characters-catch-phrases

Comment: http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/7302/are-the-peculiar-one-piece-laughs-based-on-anything

Comment: @Darjeeling Or to be more precise, a kyara-gobi (キャラ語尾), or verbal tics that occur at the end of sentences.

Answer (score 2):

In One Piece, many characters are known to laugh in unusual ways by either adding to the typical "haha" or using different syllables entirely. These laughter patterns are often unique to individuals and may be based on their personalities or appearances. Some of the especially weird laughs are different in translated versions; for example, Caesar's "shurororo" becomes "shuhohoho" in the English manga. It should be noted that laughing style of "Fufufufu" or "Ufufufufu" is a common Japanese laughing style used for mature women in anime and manga. In addition, the common phrase "Arara" is not a laugh, but rather the Japanese version of "Oh my, oh my, oh my".

Source link below

[click here](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Laughter_Style)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/34519)

Comment: done @HappyFace

Answer (score 2):

One Piece does quite a bit across the long franchise to ensure that every plot character is remembered in a different way. In addition to being drawn differently having different suffixes or having a different laugh serves as a tool to help establish that character as a unique identity.

Caesar, Doflamingo,Gekko Moria and numerous others in the show, the manga and the movies all make use of this.

In addition to suffixes and laughs there is also gestures, like Brook asking to see your panties or chopper hiding the wrong way that are also unique to add differentiation to each character.

In summation, the above are all tropes commonly used in anime to add individuality to each character.

Answer (score -2):

I could ask you a similar question. Why do so many characters in One Piece have weird laughter styles?

Well, that's because it's a characteristic of the series. Characters laugh in specific ways (gabababa, dereshishishi, horohorohoeo etc), as well as have certain catchphrases that they repeat, like the zipper-mouth guy of CP9 - Fukuro, as well as many other characters.

It's just how the universe of One Piece operates. You shouldn't question this if you want to keep your sanity intact.

Comment: This is not an answer to this question

Comment: Yes it is. You clearly didn't read the answer you (most likely) downvoted. I advise checking the answer again. It explains the quirks of One Piece -- the catchprases that characters have as well as their laughter styles. It all ties in together.

Comment: I didn't downvote

Comment: You're speaking about laughter, the question asks about suffixes. They aren't the same.

Comment: @Bálint but I mentioned both... I compared thee two (the catch-phrases and laughter styles), as these are both characteristics of the show...